# CPU SOCKET detach from motherboard due to melting of solder?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, soldering

As the title describes,is this possible?
Videos show it definitely can..for gpu.
Thermal throttle kicks in at about 100C,not before.
Example- https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSOEyYhXWMvPYgd23Yos2Z9UHrKz6NDusgcwzkQ-2712YgpRmsL-RNW6UeG

Comment: Your picture isn’t a picture of a socket.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

The temperature that modern lead free solder melts at is well over 200 degrees Celsius.

There is no normal circumstance where electronics will melt the solder. If there is a short circuit of some sort then it would be possible to generate enough heat to melt solder.

But, it is absolutely not possible that a “hot” CPU or GPU would melt solder.

The picture you show is not of a CPU socket, and looks to be a picture of heavy gauge / high current wire. In that case there could be a short circuit or something able to melt solder. Or, it could simply be a cold solder joint.

It is much more likely the soldered connection just failed due to stress over many heat and cool cycles and the fact that lead free solder is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

I serviced electronics (not computers) for some 30 years and have seen very many such connections. This is simply a broken connection which can happen for a variety of reasons. This is not due to melting solder. In many cases it is due to mechanical stress or a weakness in the original connection.

I have seen many cases where solder did melt and it looks quite different. Typically this would be caused by a burnt component. This could be the result of some internal failure or a problem somewhere else. But bad connections as in the image are far more common.